# how do I get a div fixed and at the most front view

Tags: html, css

I am having issue with making a div element fixed and viewed at the most front at the same time. Here is the project [link](https://jsfiddle.net/n6fbxvrx/).
The problem is when I scroll the button comes at the top of the green div element. What I want instead is for the button to be under the green bar

```css
#header{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
}

#btn{
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">

</div>

<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1483638906402-d942f4840969?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=80">
<button id="btn">
Button
</button>
```

Comment: use z-index to the fixed element

Comment: and how do you do that

Comment: #header{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
  z-index:10; // increase number if needed
}

Comment: by doing this `z-index:999`  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add z-index property to header element.

```css
#header{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;

}

#btn{
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">

</div>

<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1483638906402-d942f4840969?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=80">
<button id="btn">
hello
</button>
```

Comment: perfect exactly what I am looking for

Comment: It's Nice to hear that ; )